# Download only for optional updates in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have Windows Update set to download only, to avoid unexpected restarts forced by automatic installs. However, I would also like to be able to download some optional updates and install at a later date, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure for "Later" installation option. however, you can "Hide Update" [image]

And either you can change the Settings to

[image]

So, you can "Download updates" and choose whether to install later on.

Comment: Thanks, but the settings option seems to only apply to important updates. I specifically want to download when online, but install offline.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have either *never check* or *check but let me choose to download and install*.

After you check for updates, click the optional updates.  After they are downloaded, they will sit there.  You can have to hit the button **install updates** to install them later.

Comment: I have "download updates but let me choose whether to install them". I can tick the optional ones, but they don't download, and there is only the install button to click.